# Установка Yii2-advanced

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Следуюя инструкции с сайта http://web-sprints.ru/ustanovka-yii2-na-openserver/
Пробовал установить, не работает первая команда на установку плагина, почитав еще, пробую команду
composer global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin —no-plugins
Changed current directory to C:/Users/lutsenko/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Пишет:Cannot update only a partial set of packages without a lock file present. Run `composer update` to generate a lock file.
Все... А без обновления плагинов не работает отображение стартовой страницы.
Использую composer update ->
$ composer update
Composer could not find a composer.json file in F:\openserver\ospanel\domains\Yii-app
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Все это делаю в папке с проектом... composer.json там вроде как и не должно быть, но да ладно.
f:\openserver>composer
""f:\openserver\ospanel\modules\php\PHP-7.2\php.exe"" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Это выдает мне консолька openserver-а
Ну думаю через GitBash
MINGW64 /f/openserver/ospanel/domains/Yii-app
$ composer

---

/ ****/***  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
/ /   / __ / __ `*_ / __ / __ / ***/ _ / ***/
/ /***/ /*/ / / / / / / /*/ / /*/ (**  )  **/ /
_***/_***/*/ /*/ /*/ .***/_***/****/___/*/
/_/
Composer version 2.0.8 2020-12-03 17:20:38
Хмм, а тут работает.Я честно не пойму уже приколов. Правильно ли я понимаю, мне нужно установить composer.json файл в папку с проектом, чтобы потом сделать composer update, а далее уже все требуемые команды?

Answer (score 0):

Простите, смотрел не верный гайд. Все намного проще.
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced MyLocalProject
Тут может понадобиться token от гитхаба, может посчитать что слишком большое кол-во данных скачиваете и как все установилось
В корне с проектом проинициализировать объект через команду init php.
Дальше открываем MyLocalProject/frontend/web/ -> должна выводиться стартовая страница